# differece between hibernate, leave and suspend

Tags: lubuntu, suspend, hibernate

I would like to know what the difference between those three concepts are. It seems that the closing menu becomes longer every some time, although in the end most people only uses one or two of the options.

Hibernate, suspend and leave. We all know that leave means leave, but apart of the intended punt, what does it mean in this exit (oops!) or leave menu in Ubuntu, or in my case Lubuntu 18.1?

Will we have remain and extended session any time soon? All this allows for so many jokes in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate should mean "suspend to disk". Meaning the state of all your running programs are saved to disk, the computer powers down and it will take zero battery.

Suspend means "suspend to RAM". This will take a small amount of battery while suspended, but it resume faster than hibernate.

I believe "leave" just means end the current session.